# OUTER APPLY conditionally pass values into function

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a way to conditionally pass a value into this statement?

```
    OUTER APPLY [dbo].[udf_GETVMSFleet](o.ClientNum, ou.[UnitNum]) AS orgLevels
```

What I need is to say if ou.UnitNum  = '' then ou.[TailerNum]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function calls allow expressions for parameters (unlike stored procedures)

```
OUTER APPLY [dbo].[udf_GETVMSFleet](o.ClientNum,
  CASE WHEN ou.[UnitNum] = '' THEN ou.[TailerNum] ELSE ou.[UnitNum] END
) AS orgLevels
```

Comment: gotcha, didn't know you could use a CASE statment in a join like that.

Comment: @user380432: this is a parameter :-) But you can use it in JOIN condition too as you mentioned...